# How to put four numbers from four tables into a 2 by 2 table?

Tags: sql, sas

I am doing an analysis using SAS. Each time after the analysis, I will get four tables. `Table11`, `Table12` , `Tabe21` and `Table22`.  Each table only has one number. I would like to put these four numbers(from four tables) into a 2x2 matrix.  How can I do that using SAS `proc sql`?

*For example*, when I have **1** (the only number in table 1), **2** (the only number in table 2), **3** (the only number in table 3), **4** (the only number in table 4), I would like to produce anther table that has a 2 by 2 table with these four numbers inside.

Answer (score 4):

A totally hacky, terrible way to do this might look something like this:

```
SELECT (SELECT num FROM table1), (SELECT num FROM table2)
    UNION ALL 
SELECT (SELECT num FROM table3), (SELECT num FROM table4)
```

You may have to add a "dummy" table in there after each part of the union (like `SELECT ... FROM sysibm.sysdummy1` in DB2).

I've never used SAS, so I don't know the specifics.  Maybe that (standard SQL) solution will work for you.  But like I said, it's terribly hackish, so there's probably a better way to do that.

Answer (score 2):

Probably with equivalent execution plan (using implicit cross join):

```
SELECT table11.num, table12.num
FROM table11, table12
    UNION ALL 
SELECT table21.num, table22.num
FROM table21, table22
```

Comment: Hey guys, thank you for the great help. That is a very smart way to do.  I have tried, and it does work.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly you want to go with the job-security technique.

```
with
    t11(r, c, num) as (SELECT 1, 1, num from table11),
    t12(r, c, num) as (SELECT 1, 2, num from table12),
    t21(r, c, num) as (SELECT 2, 1, num from table21),
    t22(r, c, num) as (SELECT 2, 2, num from table22)
select
    coalesce(t11.num, t21.num) as col1,
    coalesce(t12.num, t22.num) as col2
from 
    (t11 cross join t12)
    full outer join
    (t21 cross join t22)
        on t11.r = t21.r or t12.r = t22.r
```

Or if you prefer to not waste the values in column c, this might be better.

```
    case
        when t11.r * t11.c = t12.c - t12.r
        then t11.num else t21.num
    end as col1,
    case
        when t21.r * t22.r * t22.c - t21.c = t21.r + t21.c + t22.r + t22.c
        then t22.num else t12.num
    end as col2
```

Comment: Lol, I like this approach but you should rename your variables to use just capital XXKXKX and capital XXKXXKX to capitalise on us dyslexic types too

Answer (score 0):

You have received some good points/solutions above, however you may want to try to automate some checking for the existence of each data set prior to doing the joining. Something like the following:

```
data c12;
c12=32;
run;

data c21;
c21=40;
run;

data c22;
c22=12;
run;

%sysfunc(ifc(%sysfunc(exist(c11)),
             proc print data = a; run;,
             data _null_; file print; put 'Dataset "c11: was not created'; run;))
```